# How do I create an Access Form for Table 1 where two Table 1 fields have different data from a single field in Table 2?

Tags: ms-access-2010

I’m absolutely stumped by what I suspect is probably simple for those experienced with Access.  I’m brand new to Access (2010) and studying a lot, but unfortunately still confused by many basic concepts.  I’m embarrassed to admit that I have spent about 40 hours trying (unsuccessfully) to solve the specific  issue below.  Please forgive me if I haven’t included enough detail here - I’m not sure how much someone needs to know to address this.  I’m happy to edit and/or provide more information.

My question:

**How do I create a Form for creating new records / editing existing records in Table1 where two fields in Table1 have different values from a single field in Table2?  (I have better detail below)**

I want the Form to have all the records from Table1.  I have tried many different ways with queries, sub-forms, etc., but can’t pull it off.  I’m fairly certain the issue is related to how I address Table2.  Ideally, the user would be able to select from dropdowns in the form for the two fields to be updated in Table1.

I am including screenshots of a mockup of my intended Form concept, the object Relationships as I currently have them, the design and datasheet views of Table1 and the design and datasheet views of Table2.

“Table1” above is “t_PEOPLE” in the images while “Table2” is “t_COLORS.”

The object relationship types are currently one-to-many with enforced referential integrity (cascade update related fields) and the join properties are "include ALL records from 't_PEOPLE' and only those records from 't_COLORS' where the joined fields are equal."

I'm happy to send the actual database file if that helps.

I will be very grateful for any guidance - thank you!!

[image: Screenshot of mockup Form concept]
[image: Screenshot of object Relationships]
[image: Screenshot of t_PEOPLE datasheet view]
[image: Screenshot of t_PEOPLE design view]
[image: Screenshot of t_COLORS datasheet view]
[image: Screenshot of t_COLORS design view]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach to this is as follows:

A)  If I understand what you're trying to do here, your t_colors table is usually referred to as a Reference table or Lookup table. You need to make one form to add, edit, and delete records in this t_colors table. How the user accesses that form varies. I'll get to that in a minute.

B) The form for your People table needs to have drop down menus for your two color selections. In the dropdown menus' RowSource, you will use a query that looks up values in your t_colors table.

C) Depending what you are using your colors for in t_people, you should consider making a third table with PeopleID and ColorID in it. It would then link to both t_people and t_colors. This would allow you to have multiple colors specified for a single person, and you wouldn't be limited to two. In your People form, you would use a subform for these colors. The subform would probably need to be a datasheet form or a continuous form. If you are using a datasheet form for your people form, then you would need to use a datasheet form for the colors subform.

If the user wants to use a color that isn't already in your t_colors table, you need to give them a way of inserting that color. There are various approaches to this. You could use a union query in the dropdowns RowSource that shows a "" option. If selected you would bring up your Colors form and when they close the colors form you have to requery your dropdown menu. Or you could insert the color for them using VBA when they enter a value that is "Not In List" (an event that Combobox's have).

Please note that the relationships you've defined are not overly helpful or important in this case. Yes, they can be helpful when it comes to using the Update Cascade or Delete Cascade features. But quite truthfully, relationships are basically for programmers, to make sure you get an error if and when referential integrity is violated. Users should never see these errors and properly designed forms will prevent them from occurring. The main reason to use them is that it will force you to design your forms properly by giving you an error when something is wrong, hopefully during your own testing phase of the project.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! I appreciate the fast response on your part and apologize for my delay in replying: I was working to incorporate your guidance and it took me a while to understand (because of my ignorance, not your answer).  The combobox led me in the right direction, especially the tip about the RowSource.  I did not need to use subforms.  I admit I didn't understand what you were driving at with the suggestion for a third table (again, my ignorance!) but didn't need to pursue it since the choices for colors must be limited to two and the Comboboxes did the trick.  I'm very grateful!

Comment: Forgot:  I also set "Show Only Row Source Value" to "Yes" in the Data tab of the combobox Property Sheet so it would only have the color names in the combobox instead of the colorID values.

Comment: Ok, now i realize I need to do a third table as you suggest above.  this is for a new field I want to update in t_PEOPLE and have the ability to do multiple selections.  I don't understand how to setup the third table - can you help again?  Thanks!!

Comment: If your question about the third table is different from your original question then you should probably open a new SO question.